# I was wondering what time signature is this song written in?

Tags: theory

I was wondering if anyone could determine in what time signature is this piece? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, but this site isn't about analysis of songs in this way. So the question will soon be closed. However, it's very easy to count and work out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The song is in 4/4, but there is some rubato in places.

Comment: By providing answers to questions that will inevitably be closed, it's encouraging others to ask similar.